# find the latest modified file and exec

Tags: bash, shell, find

I want to find out the latest built rpm in a directory and then exec something on it. Something similar to below.

```
/bin/ls -1t srcdir/*.rpm | head -1
```

But with the find command

```
find srcdir/*.rpm <get-only-the-most-recently-modified-file> -exec "<do-something>"
```

Comment: Since your question involves improving already working code, would it not be more suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Actually, I need to do much more than just `cp`. I've modified the question.

Comment: Actually, none of @CharlesDuffy's solution gives you the latest built rpm, perhaps you wanted latest modified file(remember even a `touch file` modifies the access time) as correctly mentioned in the title and correctly addressed by his solution.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm safe to assume that the latest rpm is the last modified file (in my case)

Comment: I stop earlier if the build fails and no one is going to `touch` the rpm files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two approaches -- one portable to non-GNU platforms, the other fast with large directories (to the extent allowed by the filesystem):

---

## Portable

#### What?

[BashFAQ #3: How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) is relevant here. To summarize:

```
latest=
for f in "$srcdir"/*.rpm; do
  [ "$f" -nt "$latest" ] && latest=$f
done
```

#### How?

`[ "$a" -nt "$b" ]` checks whether the file named in variable `a` is newer than that named in variable `b` in ksh-derived shells.

---

## Fast

...to be clear, this is faster with very large directories, as opposed to faster in all cases. That said, it's also easily adapted to find (for instance) the 5 or 10 newest files, or all files *except* those 5 or 10 newest, which the other approach could not do nearly as effectively.

#### What?

If you have GNU tools (GNU find, GNU sort), consider the following:

```
{ read -r -d ' ' mtime && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; } \
  < <(find /directory -type f -iname "*.rpm" -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -z -r -n)
```

This will put your latest file's time (in seconds-since-epoch) in the shell variable `mtime` and the name of that file in `filename`. Thus, you can then operate on that file:

```
if [[ -e $filename ]]; then
  # do whatever arbitrary operations you're looking for on that resulting filename
  cp -- "$filename" /path/to/where/to/copy
fi
```

---

#### How?

To explain how this works:

```
find ... -printf '%T@ %p\0'
```

...emits contents in the format `<epoch_mtime> <filename><NUL>`, where `epoch_mtime` is the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970.

```
sort -z -r -n
```

...then sorts that output, expecting it to be NUL-delimited, on the numbers at the beginning.

```
{ read -r -d ' ' mtime && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; }
```

...reads content into the `mtime` variable up to the first space in the first line, and then reads forward to the first NUL into the `filename` variable.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you just wish to see the latest rpm :

```
ls -1tr /pat/to/directory/*.rpm | tail -n 1
```

is good. But since [[ ls output **shouldn't** be parsed ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you need to look to `find` for a remedy if you plan to use the file for some purpose as is in  your case.

My Solution would be :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i lts # latest time stamp
declare -i cts # current time stamp
declare latestrpmfile="No file available"
lts=0
while read -r -d '' fname
do
  cts="$( stat --printf=%Y "$fname" )"
if [ "$cts" -gt "$lts" ]
then
  lts="$cts"
  latestrpmfile="$fname"
fi
done < <( find /directory/to/rpm/files/ -type f -iname "*.rpm" -print0 )

#At this point $latestrpmfile will contain the full path to the 
#latest rpm file
#Now, say, to copy the latest rpm file to a directory, do
if [ -e "$latestrpmfile" ]
then
  cp "$latestrpmfile" /path/to/where/to/copy/
fi
```

---

**Problem specific solution**

```
lbt=0 #latest build time
lb="nosuchfile" #latest build
for i in "$srcdir"/*.rpm # source dir could be an argument to script
do
bt=$(rpm -q --queryformat "%{BUILDTIME}" -p "$i" 2>/dev/null)
if [ "$bt" -gt "$lbt" ]
then
  lbt=$bt
  lb="$i"
fi
done
#Do something with "$lb"
```

Comment: If you have GNU `find`, why not have it extract the times for you? Much cheaper than a `stat` call per file.

Comment: ...it's worth noting that this depends on GNU `stat`; `--printf` isn't standardized. (My answer isn't POSIX-compliant either -- for a fully portable solution neither of our approaches work).

Comment: ...actually, I've amended my answer to be have a solution with no dependencies on tools that aren't built into bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Thankyou, on re-reading the question, `latest built rpm in a directory` caught my attention. The op might be looking for file-birth time, for which I may use `stat --printf=%W` but this is file system dependent and not very reliable. I just saw your update, great stuff

Comment: Hmm. Actually, if you wanted actual build time rather than local mtime, that might be a `rpm -Q --format=... -f "$filename"` invocation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : pls see the update that incorporates your suggestion.

Comment: +1 for that. (That said, I think you might redact the "only viable solution" note, as I believe I've demonstrated multiple alternatives).

Comment: (btw, on the rpm command, is the `-a` doing anything in conjunction with `-p`?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `a` is not needed here. Updated :)