# Bash script invalid space sign

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My goal is it is to gate time in second for last modified file in catalog.

I have catalog with space in name and want to `stat` it with script. With a terminal I simply use:

```
sudo stat -c %Y /var/www/pre/data/jko/files/My\ Files
```

and works perfectly.
In my `bash` script i read files one by one from directory `/var/www/pre/data/jko/files/` with (this is inside while loop)

```
touch tempFile.txt
#ls sort by last modified date
sudo ls -rt /var/www/pre/data/$line/files/ > tempFile.txt 
# read newest file
outputFile=$(tail -1 tempFile.txt) 
# replace all spaces with "\ " sign
outputFile=$(echo ${outputFile// /"\ "})
outputDirectoryToFile=/var/www/pre/data/$line/files/$outputFile
echo $outputDirectoryToFile
expr `sudo date +%s` - `sudo stat -c %Y $outputDirectoryToFile`
```

And if i fire this script with `bash script.sh` i got

```
/var/www/pre/data/jko/files/My\ Files //line from echo
stat: cannot stat '/var/www/pre/data/jko/files/My\': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat 'Files': No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
```

Or maybe there is simpler solution

Comment: Quote it: `sudo stat -c '%Y' "/var/www/pre/data/jko/files/My Files"`

Comment: Creating literal quotes (quotes in your data) in no way substitutes for missing syntactic quotes (quotes in your code). They're two completely different things.

Comment: BTW, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- `ls` should not be used programatically.

Comment: ...BashFAQ #3, at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003, describes best practices around finding the newest/oldest/etc. file.

Comment: ...see the *very* closely related (maybe even a duplicate?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571882/find-the-latest-modified-file-and-exec/38575205#38575205

Comment: ...so, the whole `${outputFile// /"\ "}` thing is entirely misguided. Remove that, and add missing quotes -- http://shellcheck.net/ is an excellent static checker (which you can download and locally install) which will, among other things, find places where your scripts are missing quotes which are needed for correctness.

Comment: BTW, re: gating, do you mean you only want files older than a certain age? That's something GNU `find` can do for you automatically. See the `-newerXY`, particularly the `-newermt` formulation of same, and also `-mtime` or `-mmin`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Correctly, and efficiently, finding the latest file in a directory

```
{ read -r -d ' ' mtime && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; } \
  < <(find /directory -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -z -r -n)
```

...will put the time in seconds for the most-recently-modified file in the shell variable `mtime`, and the name of this file in the shell variable `filename`.

Moreover, it will work even with files with surprising or intentionally malicious names -- filenames with newline literals in their names, filenames with glob characters, etc. I have a more complete explanation of this idiom and why it works [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571882/find-the-latest-modified-file-and-exec/38575205#38575205).

---

#### Why your original code didn't work

Now, what was wrong with your original code? In short: **Literal quotes do not substitute for syntactic quotes**. Let's go into what this means.

In `/var/www/pre/data/jko/files/My\ Files`, the backslash is *syntactic*: It's shell syntax. When you run `stat /var/www/pre/data/jko/files/My\ Files`, the result is a syscall that looks like the following:

```
execv("/usr/bin/stat", "stat", "/var/www/pre/data/jko/files/My Files")
```

Note how the backslash is gone? That's because the shell consumed it when it was parsing the string.

The following are all *exactly* identical:

```
# each of these assigns the same string to the variable named s
s=Hello\ World
s=Hello" "World
s='Hello World'
```

...and they can be expanded as follows:

```
# this passes the *exact* contents of that variable as an argument to stat, and thus tries
# to stat a file named Hello World (no literal quotes in the name):
stat "$s"
```

In the above, the quotes are again *syntactic* -- they're telling the shell not to split the result of the variable expansion into multiple separate words or evaluate it as a glob -- not *literal*, in which case they would be passed to `stat` as part of its argument.

---

So, what happens when you run `s=${s// /'\ '}`? You're putting **literal** backslashes into the data.

Thereafter:

```
s="Hello World"
s=${s// /'\ '}    # change string to 'Hello\ World'
stat "$s"         # try to stat a file named 'Hello\ World', with the backslash
```

What happens if you leave out the syntactic double quotes on the expansion? It's even uglier:

```
s="Hello World"
s=${s// /'\ '}    # change string to 'Hello\ World'
stat $s           # try to stat a file named 'Hello\', and a second file named 'World'
```

That's because unquoted expansion doesn't run through all shell parsing steps; it only does field splitting and glob expansion.

Answer (score 1):

If you paths contain spaces, quote them all to avoid problems:

```
touch tempFile.txt
sudo ls -rt "/var/www/pre/data/$line/files/" > tempFile.txt //ls sort by last modified date
outputFile=$(tail -1 tempFile.txt) // read newest file
outputDirectoryToFile="/var/www/pre/data/$line/files/$outputFile"
echo $outputDirectoryToFile
expr `sudo date +%s` - `sudo stat -c %Y "$outputDirectoryToFile"`
```

Comment: This still has some unquoted expansions in it, though they're ones less likely to cause problems. (The command substitutions being called to generate `expr` arguments, for instance, are unquoted; same for the argument to `echo` -- would could matter if, say, `IFS=/`, or if the filename contained content that could be evaluated as a glob).